# Unity NullReferenceException when object has just been assigned

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I've got a GameObject that is being instantiated:

```
var face = Instantiate(waveConfigs[waveNumber].getFacePrefab(), waypoint.position, Quaternion.identity, FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform);

Debug.Log(face, this);
faces.Add(face);
```

`faces` is declared above like this:

```
List<GameObject> faces;
```

The object gets instantiated, the DebugLog is follows:

```
Smile(Clone) (UnityEngine.GameObject)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FaceSpawner:SpawnFaces(Int32) (at Assets/Scripts/FaceSpawner.cs:30)
FaceSpawner:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/FaceSpawner.cs:16)
```

(Which is the Debug.Log(face, this);)

And then straight after that, when I call `faces.Add()`:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
FaceSpawner.SpawnFaces (System.Int32 waveNumber) (at Assets/Scripts/FaceSpawner.cs:31)
FaceSpawner.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/FaceSpawner.cs:16)
```

I dont get it, I've literally *just* assigned this variable, its worked, it appears on the canvas, I can log it out the debuglog, and then when I try and add it to a List I get a NullReference.  What is going on here?

Comment: You assign `face` not `faces`

Comment: `List<GameObject> faces;` is a deceleration but *not* an assignment which means that `faces` does not point to an object in memory so it returns `null`. You have to assign it to a new or existing instance of an `List<GameObject>` if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `faces` container been initialized likewise `List<GameObject> faces = new  List<GameObject>()`?

The thing is you're trying to `Add` to the container which hasn't been created, that is for which memory hasn't been allocated yet and for which its constructors hasn't been called. So basically you're trying to call function `Add` on non existent object.

Comment: In the declarations I just have `List<GameObject> faces;` - do i need to be more specific?

Comment: Yes you have to allocate the memory for your `faces` container first, just as I pointed out in the answer

Comment: Thanks.  It didnt occur to me that `faces` was the problem, I thought it was `face`.  I'll mark your answer as correct!